# dnsmasq cannot start after Ubuntu update

Tags: 18.04, bind, dnsmasq

I had Ubuntu 16.04 which I recently upgraded to 18.04.
On 16.04 I had dnsmasq with running configuration in parallel with bind.
After upgrade, I am not able to start dnsmasq due to following error:

`dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use`.

I can check Active Internet connections via `netstat -tulpn` and I see that `named` is using same IP and port (127.0.0.1:53) as configured in dnsmasq.conf (listen-address=127.0.0.1)

Could you help me to solve this issue ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

`DNSStubListener=no` didn't help.

But according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq I used
`port=0` in dnsmasq.conf and this solved my problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A port conflict with `dnsmasq` is usually caused by `systemd-resolved` running.  With 18.04, `systemd-resolved` became enabled by default.  `systemd-resolved` basically provides a local DNS caching server.

There are other pages about options for fixing this. e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-dnsmasq-and-systemd-resolved

Based on what you found about the port being used by `named`, then you may have a different conflict with `bind`.  The same concept applies. You can disable `bind`, or you can configure the services to listen on non-conflicting addresses and ports.